# With MongoDb, is importing bson more performant than json?

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport

Suppose you are planning a large import of millions of documents to an existing MongoDb collection (the existing documents must be preserved).

You have the choice between receiving the new documents in bson or json format.  If the document files are in bson format, will importing them be much faster/more efficient/easier on the database than if they were in json format?

Comment: You are not using specific terminology which makes the question too ambiguous to have a meaningful answer. "import" is not a MongoDB operation, there are inserts. What language is doing the inserts? Are you taking input parsing time into account? In most drivers (except for C perhaps) you won't be providing input to inserts in either bson or json.

Comment: @D.SM according to the tags he clearly likes to use the mongoimport tool for import.

Comment: The import with mongoimport is exactly the same, you just specify the format with command line parameters. Which one is faster? - run a simple test! I guess the difference will be minimal